# Question about non-archimedean local fields: how is $(1 + \mathfrak{m}^n) \langle\pi\rangle$ finite index open subgroup?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a non-archimedean local field. Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be the maximal ideal of $O_K$ and $\pi$ a uniformizing parameter of $O_K$. Could someone please explain me how $(1 + \mathfrak{m}^n) \langle\pi\rangle$ is an open finite index subgroup of $K^*$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$U_K/(1+\mathfrak m^n)\to K^*/(1+\mathfrak m^n)\left<\pi \right>$$
induced by the inclusion $U_K\to K^*$  is an isomorphic.
$$U_K/(1+\mathfrak m^n)\cong (\mathfrak O_K/\mathfrak m^n)^*$$
is finite, since $|\mathfrak O_K/\mathfrak m^n|=|k|^n$
where $k$ is the (finite) residue class field of $K$.

As $1+\mathfrak m^n$ is open, so is $(1+\mathfrak m^n)\left<\pi \right>$.

Comment: PS Actually one question. What are you using for the topology on $K^*$ here?

Comment: @JohnnyT. I hope the same one as you!

Comment: I am actually getting confused with this material I am reading and I don't know what it is... Could you possibly tell me what you used? (I first thought it was the subspace topology but I am starting to guess it is not?)

Comment: A local field is a metric space...

Comment: Right, so I get that we can use that for $K$, but for $K^*$ we just use the subspace topology induced by that?

Comment: Yes, you can @JohnnyT.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I guess I really need to figure out what the source is using... I have tried looking into it more but it is still not clear to me.